How to level floor in house with crawlspace?
We have a wood frame house with a crawlspace. Our floors are not level because the floor joists are spaced farther apart than they should be (according to code now - house was built in the 80s). What should I be looking for/asking when I get quotes for this? What kind of contractor should I be looking for?

A building contractor, but if you can give more information, it might help.  Joists are usually 16 inches apart.  The size of the joists plus the span they cross are important also.  Finding out why the floors are not level is the most important.

Unless you mean the 1880s, floor framing hasn't changed substantially since then. Something else is going on.

Your title asks one thing and your post another. Please revise one of them so they match. Also take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Are the floors sagging in one area, or tilted to one side? How do you know that the joist spacing is causing the problem?  What is the joist spacing?  What is the subfloor material? This could be something serious, or an issue easily remedied. Please provide additional pertinent information.

If you are looking for someone to pull permits, remove the old floor, install new joists (or sister to old joists), install a vapor barrier and insulation, move and/or reinstall any electrical and plumbing, then install new floor coverings and then mouldings, then you need a general contractor.
If you are looking for someone to just install the joist, then any competent carpenter will do.

I don't see how this answer is likely to be useful.  It addresses one extreme or the other without guidance as to which, if either, would be likely to help.  I would favor the questions/comments from crip659, isherwood, and RMDman for responses that move toward a solution.

OP asked " What kind of contractor should I be looking for?" I explained the two ends. The OPs answer is probably somewhat in the middle, but I'm not there and can't read their mind
